# For Which $a$ This Is A linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the be vectors
>
> $w_1=(1,1,2),w_2=(2,1,1),w_3=(1,2,a)$ and $v_1=(1,2,1),v_2=(1,1,2),v_3=(2,a,1)$
>
> 1. Find for which values of $a$ the transformation $$T(w_1)=T(v_1),T(w_2)=T(v_2),T(w_3)=T(v_3)$$
>      is linear transformation
> 2. for $a=1$ find the explicit formula of the linear transformation $T(x,y,z)=...$
> 3. Find the inverse linear transformation of $2.$

1. For a transformation to be linear we need $T(w_1+w_2+w_3)=v_1+v_2+v_3$

So $$T((4,4,a+3))=T((1,1,2)+(2,1,1)+(1,2,a))=((1,2,1)+(1,1,2)+(2,a,1))=(4,3+a,4)$$ So we need

$$T((4,4,a+3))=(4,3+a,4)$$ or $$a+3=4\iff a=1$$

2. We will define the transformation on a basis and find how its work on a general vector in the span of the basis vectors.

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 &1\\
1 & 1 & 2\\
2 &1 &1
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 &0 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the vectors are linearly independent and are $3$ so they are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Now we will write $(x,y,z)\in Span(w_1,w_2,w_3)$

$$
  \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 1 & x \\
    1 & 1 & 2 & y \\
    2 & 1 & 1 & z
  \end{array}\right)\Rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4}(-x-y+3z) \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{4}(3x-y-z) \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{4}(-x+3y-z)
  \end{array}\right)
$$

So $$(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4}(-x-y+3z)\cdot w_1+\frac{1}{4}(3x-y-z)\cdot w_2+\frac{1}{4}(-x+3y-z)\cdot w_3$$

Taking the linear transformation on both sides we get

$$T(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4}(-x-y+3z)\cdot (1,2,1)+\frac{1}{4}(3x-y-z)\cdot (1,1,2)+\frac{1}{4}(-x+3y-z)\cdot (2,1,1)=(y,z,x)$$

3. Taking the Transformation on the standard basis we get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 &0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is inverse is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 &1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 &1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: 2 and 3 are okay. But 1 makes no sense.

Comment: You mean T(w1+w2+w3=T(w1)+T(w2)+T(w3)=v1+v2+v3?

Comment: that is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: Ok got it, need to check T(aw)=aT(w) too

Comment: There is a theorem like "a linear map is uniquely defined by its values on a basis"

Comment: Yes, I wanted to write it! So just need to check it is a basis. But what if we send an element of a basis let say w to v+1, this is not a linear transformation

Comment: what do you mean?